# How to create object of an anonymous class which is inner class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to create object of an anonymous class which is inner class `Inner` in kotlin

```
private val outerIsSuper = outer.OuterIsSuper(2)
val x = object : outerIsSuper.Inner() {}
```

Where Inner class is

```
open class Outer(protected val value: Int) {
    open inner class OuterIsNotSuper {
      fun getValue(): Int {
        return value
      }
    }
 inner class OuterIsSuper(i: Int) : Outer(i) {}
}
```

is this possible and how is the syntax? Thanks

Comment: Why is `generics` tagged?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Good observation. Took the liberty to remove tag `generics` from the question. BR